# Is $\{x \in c_0: |x_2|\le 1\}$ weakly closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X = c_0$ ($c_0$ — Banach space of sequences converging to zero). We have a set: $A_1 = \{x \in c_0: |x_2|\le 1\}$ ($x_2$ — coordinate of vector $x$). Is this subset of $c_0$ closed in weak topology?

I have readed this post [Closure of a set in the weak topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871470/closure-of-a-set-in-the-weak-topology) and I do not understand how to answer in this case, because as i see it's infinite dimensional case.

Comment: $A_1$ is the empty set.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry my bad, edited

Comment: Prove that $A_1=f^{-1}([-1,1])$ for some $f\in(c_0)'=\ell^1$, cf. [your post from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589371). This will prove that $A_1$ is closed.

Comment: @OuoDoulo, you can use that a convex closed set is weakly closed.

Comment: @thing is this a theorem, can i see it please? Is it works only with convex sets?

Comment: @thing Also if we have convex set, can we say because of necessity: if closed in weak => closed in stronger, that closeness and openness match for both topology?

Comment: Yes, it's theorem (I don’t remember whose it is, it seems to be Mazur's). Should be argued like this: compact and closed convex sets can be strictly separated by a functional. This means that your set can be strictly separated from a point that does not lie in the set (since a one-point set is compact). This means that for any point that does not lie in the set, there exists a weak neighborhood that also does not lie in the set. Hence, the complement is weakly open.

Answer (score 1):

$A_1=f^{-1}([-1,1])$ where $f$ is the element $x\mapsto x_2$ of $(c_0)'.$ Since $f$ is weakly continuous (by the very definition of the weak topology) and $[-1,1]$ is closed, $A_1$ is weakly closed.